# How to select a specific Model from a Join Query in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a 3 models

- `user`
- `helper`
- `order`

`user` is connected to `helper` with a *Many-to-Many* `helper_user` pivot table, and connected to `orders` with *Many-to-Many* `order_user` pivot table.

I can easily select `helpers`'s `user`s by

```
class Helper extends Model {
...
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
    }
...
}
```

And I can easily select `user`'s `order`s by

```
class User extends Model {
...
    public function orders() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
    }
...
}
```

**But how do I select `helper`'s `order`s?**

I tried:

```
class Helper extends Model {
...
    public function orders() {
        return $this->users()->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')->select('orders.*');
    }
...
}
```

This returns `order`s, but their class is `App\User`.

Comment: `helper` and `order` are connected through `user` table. Not sure how you define this relationship. But you can easily fetch the `helper's order's` with foreach loop. `foreach($helper->users as $user) $helpers_orders[] = $user->orders->toArray();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to define a method in helper model for a relationship with orders. You may fetch order using [dot syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

```
$usersOrders = App\Helper::with('users.orders')->get();
```